# Is this a scam or not a scam?

Tags: banking, money-transfer, scams

I received the below email. Is is a scam or not a scam?

> Attention: Mohamed Atef,
>
> May the peace of the Lord be with you.
>
> Yes He left an ATM/VISA CARD with me before he traveled out of the
>   country, He ask me to send it to you, but do not know how to convert a
>   card to money when he did not give me the pin code due to security
>   reasons. He said that as soon as you confirm that you have received
>   the ATM CARD that his bank will give me the code so that I will send
>   it to you for onward withdrawal of your money.
>
> I will need your full name, address and telephone number, to enable me
>   gives it to courier Service Company so that they will deliver it to
>   you.
>
> I will be waiting for you to send to me your full address.
>
> God bless, Rev. James Koko

Comment: Do you know the sender? Who is "he" that the message talks about, and do you know them?

Comment: 100% scam. Stay away

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this is a scam? How could it not be?

Comment: @glglgl I got fewer than 10 words in before realising its a scam so I agree that it should be obvious but somethings aren't as obvious to some people as they are to others.

Comment: @glglgl - think about this. If no one ever fell for a particular scam, that scam wouldn't exist. An email is cheap, a dollar per 100K or 1M? So it doesn't take too many responders to make it profitable.

Comment: @glglgl : please read this short comic page https://xkcd.com/1053/  and then think about whether it's really constructive to be smug about people who hear about it for the first time. As you surely weren't born with information about these types of  scams already embedded into your mind, there must have been a point in time when you yourself didn't know about it.

Comment: @vsz You are right. I always draw conclusions from me to other people, which is just wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a few questions for you:

1. Do you know who He is other than `Lord`, `God` or `Almighty`?
2. Did you lose your ATM card?
3. Do you know the person who emailed you (in your case: Rev James Koko)?
4. If you don't know the person who emailed you (James Koko), do you know how this person may have your email but not info about where you live or your phone number?
5. Do you think someone would just give you free money?
6. If someone you know asked that person to mail you the ATM, why would that person worry about PIN to take out cash and then send you the card. Does that make sense?

If the answer to any of the above is `No` then it is a scam.
Further, here are some more questions:

1. Did this mail go to spam/junk?
2. Does the email ID of the sender look weird/odd?

If the answer to either is `Yes` then it is a scam. In fact you could safely apply these rules for most emails of such nature.